# How to swap position of tab bar item when refactored storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7, uitabbaritem

When i refactored storyboard same photo in this 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8YS8.png).

I can't find where i can swap position of tab bar item. 

example i want to change main menu to index 0. 

this is my [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99rZy.png).

Comment: You have to remove all your viewControllers item from Tab Bar Controller. After that add them again in order you want. There is no other way.

Comment: ok that work! thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all relation and start making from MainMenu to what you want at the end.

Answer (score 6):

You can just re-arrange the order by `dragging and dropping` the icons in the tab bar controller

If you are using custom tabs, you can still drag and drop to reorder even though the `Tab Bar Controller` scene shows a grey bar, the bar item is still there. This is especially inconspicuous when all your bar item are `custom items`.